# Im try to make interrupts in my OS with macros. What does this construction mean in C?

Tags: c

```
#define IRQ_HANDLER(name) void name(); \
    asm(#name ": pusha \n call _" #name " \n movb $0x20, %al \n outb %al, $0x20 \n outb %al, $0xA0 \n popa \n iret"); \
    void _##name()
```

What does `_##name()` mean? I know that `#name` means `"name"`, but what is `##name`?

Comment: It is token concatenation: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Concatenation.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`#`is the stringize preprocessor operator

`##`is the token pasting or token concatenation preprocessor operator. When the macro is expanded both sides of `##` are combined and make one identifier. Such that in your example the `_` will be concatenated to the name given in argument to the macro.